# Extends method display blank page

Tags: php, symfony, twig

It's my first project in Symfony and I just create a new controller "Homecontroller" with render function :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

So this function catch my index.html.twig file and in it, I just have this line.

My index.html.twig :

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
```

My base.html.twig :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.1.1">
    <title>Carousel Template · Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<main role="main">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                        <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
                        <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>


    <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

    <div class="container marketing">

        <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->


        <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it’s that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="container">
        <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2017-2020 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
    </footer>
</main>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why do I have a blank page when I just want to display my base.html.twig ?
I suppose it's a block or content problem but I'm stuck ...

Comment: Enable twig's debug when developing to show the error

Comment: Ok so the documentation says that i need to use dump function. I wrote {% dump "base.html.twig" %} in my index.html.twig just after my extends method but nothing appears. I saw that I also need to set a TWIG environment and load my template for display errors but I can't see how to name this file and where add it. Thanks for your time

Comment: Did you check `PHP`'s error log then already?

Comment: Yes I did and there is no error just a blank page, as if base.html.twig was empty ...

Comment: My guess would be kinda be that views are in a wrong directory, mind posting your directory structure

Comment: @B.Gregoire perhaps you are running in production mode?
If that's the case, try deleting your cache (`bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`)

Comment: @DarkBee [link](https://pasteboard.co/KcDrrAtm.png) On the left my file/folder structure

Comment: @player-one [link](https://pasteboard.co/KcDrrAtm.png) On the right my .env file and i'm on dev mode ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your `base.html.twig` has no points of extension.

You need to define block like this in `base.html.twig`:

```
{% block main %}{% endblock %}
```

And then in your `index.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block main %}
{# your page contents here #}
{% endblock %}
```